# Newsletter: Passing subscriber email address to the custom block

Tags: blocks, template, cms, newsletter

I have a newsletter in my store and in the cms notation of the newsletter templates I have included a block to fill the content. I need to pass the subscriber email address to the block so that I can make changes in the content (based on the Customer). 
I know that subscriber.getEmail will return the email address but how will I pass it to the block in cms page?

I tried -

```
{{block type="..." template="..." email="{{var subscriber.getEmail()}}" }}
```

But its not working as expected. How to pass the subscribers email to the template/block ?

Comment: hi @ted any solution on this ?